# Show that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|f(x)|^2dx = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|\hat{f}(\mu)|^2d\mu$

Tags: linear-algebra, integration, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

**Given:** Let $a_1 \lt b_1 \le a_2 \lt b_2 \le ... \le a_{n-1} \lt b_{n-1} \le a_n \lt b_n$ and let $$f(x) = \sum_{j=1}^nc_jf_{a_jb_j}(x).$$

**Show that**,
$$(*)\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|f(x)|^2dx = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|\hat{f}(\mu)|^2d\mu$$

**My intuition** is first using the fact that (I proved that):

$$(1)\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1-costx}{x^2}dx = |t|\pi \quad,\forall t\in \mathbb R$$

In order to show that:

$$(2)\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\hat{f}_{a_jb_j}(\mu)\overline{\hat{f}_{a_jb_j}(\mu)}d\mu = 0 \quad for\;i \neq j$$

and then use $(2)$ to show what is required. I'm still not sure how to get from $(1)$ to $(2)$ and from $(2)$ to show $(*)$

**My intuition** for showing $(2)$ is using:

$$g(\mu) = \hat{f}_{cd}(\mu)\overline{\hat{f}_{ab}(\mu)} = \{\frac{e^{i\mu d}-e^{i\mu c}}{i\mu}\}\{\frac{\overline{e^{i\mu b}-e^{i\mu a}}}{i\mu}\} = \frac{e^{i\mu (d-b)}-e^{i\mu (c-b)}-e^{i\mu (d-a)} + e^{i\mu(c-a)}}{\mu^2}$$

And somehow and exploit the fact that $g(\lambda)$ is holomorphic in $\mathbb C$ and the coefficients of $i\mu$
in the exponential terms in $g(\mu)$ are all nonnegative.

Also, another intuition is showing (still don't know how - **would highly appreciate if someone can solve this** too) that:

$$(*)(*)\lim\limits_{R \uparrow \infty}\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-R}^{R}e^{-i\mu x}\hat{f}_{ab}(\mu)d\mu = f_{ab}(x)$$ and from that to show $(*)$.

where $f_{ab}(x)$ and $\hat{f}_{ab}(\mu)$ are:
[image]

**Let the Fourier transform** $\hat{f}(\mu)$ of a function $f(x)$ specified on $\mathbb R$ is defined (often) by the formula:

$\hat{f}(\mu) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{i\mu x}f(x)dx$ for $\mu \in \mathbb C$ whenever the integral makes sense.

**Let** $f_{ab}(x) = 1$ for $a \le x \le b$ and $f_{ab}(x) = 0$ for $x \neq [a,b]$.

the points $x$ are $\in \mathbb R$ except for $a, b$.

Comment: What is known about $f$ and the $f_{ab}$? Are they in $L^1(\Bbb R)$?

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch I've edited the question, hopefully it makes more sense now. :)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I've edited the question, hopefully it makes more sense now. :)

Comment: Your (\*)(\*) is a standard classical inversion for the Fourier transform of a piecewise smooth function.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts I see, and how about $(*)$? Any ideas how to approach it or use $(*)(*)$?

Comment: Start with a pair of characteristic functions. (\*) can follow from (\*)(\*). Show $\int \hat{\chi_[a,b]}\overline{\hat{\chi_{[c,d]}}}d\xi = \int_a^b\chi_{[c,d]}dx$

Comment: In the previous comment, show the equality by taking the limit of $\int_{-R}^{R}$ on the left side, and use (\*).

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS you might want to check Parseval's theorem. What you want to prove is exactly that.

Comment: @sudeep5221 Yeah, but i still don't manage to use Parseval's theorem to address this.

Comment: Do you know that $\lim_{R\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-R}^{R}e^{ixs}\hat{f}(s)ds=\frac{1}{2}(f(x+0)+f(x-0))$ for $f=\chi_{[a,b]}$?

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS: I honestly do not understand your question: this is nothing but [Plancherel's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plancherel_theorem), and the extra $\frac 1 {2 \pi}$ is due to your choice of definition of the Fourier transform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pointwise result is typically needed for such a proof. For example,
$$
      \lim_{R\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-R}^{R}e^{isx}\widehat{\chi_{[a,b]}}(s)ds = \frac{1}{2}(\chi_{[a,b]}(x)+\chi_{(a,b)}(x)) \;\;(*)
$$
The form on the right is a convenient way to express a function that is equal to the mean of the left- and right-hand limits of $\chi_{[a,b]}$ at each point. This is a special case of the pointwise Fourier inversion theorem applied to $\chi_{[a,b]}$.

Equation (*) may be written as
$$
   \lim_{R\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-R}^{R}e^{isx}\int_{a}^{b}e^{-ist}dtds = \frac{1}{2}(\chi_{[a,b]}(x)+\chi_{(a,b)}(x)) \\
  \lim_{R\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{a}^{b}\frac{e^{iR(x-t)}-e^{-iR(x-t)}}{2i(x-t)}dx= \frac{1}{2}(\chi_{[a,b]}(x)+\chi_{(a,b)}(x)) \\
  \lim_{R\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{a}^{b}\frac{\sin(R(x-t))}{x-t}dx = \frac{1}{2}(\chi_{[a,b]}(x)+\chi_{(a,b)}(x))
$$
Using this inversion,
\begin{eqnarray*}
   & &\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\widehat{\chi_{[a,b]}}(s)\overline{\widehat{\chi_{[c,d]}}(s)}ds \\
  & &= \lim_{R\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-R}^{R}
        \int_{a}^{b}\int_{c}^{d}e^{-isx}e^{isy}dxdyds \\
  & &=  \lim_{R\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{a}^{b}\int_{c}^{d} \frac{e^{iR(y-x)}-e^{-iR(y-x)}}{i(y-x)}dxdy \\
  & &=  \lim_{R\rightarrow\infty}\int_{a}^{b}\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{c}^{d}\frac{\sin(R(y-x))}{y-x}dxdy \\
  & &= \int_{a}^{b} \chi_{[c,d]}(y)dy
%% = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\chi_{[a,b]}(x)\chi_{[c,d]}(x) dx \\
  = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \chi_{[a,b]}(x)\overline{\chi_{[c,d]}(x)}dx.
\end{eqnarray*}
In particular, the above is $0$ if $[a,b]\cap [c,d]$ is empty or has zero length. Everything you want follows from the last identity, which is already a special case of what you want to prove.

DETAIL: You want to show that the following converges to $\chi_{[a,b](x)}$ as $R\rightarrow\infty$ for $x\ne a$ and $x\ne b$:
$$
   \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-R}^{R}e^{isx}\widehat{\chi_{[a,b]}}(s)ds \\
 = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-R}^{R} e^{isx}\int_a^b e^{-isu}duds \\ 
 = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{a}^{b}\int_{-R}^{R}e^{is(x-u)}ds du \\
 = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_a^b\frac{\sin(R(u-x))}{u-x} du \\
 = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{a-x}^{b-x}\frac{\sin(Rv)}{v}dv \\
 = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{R(a-x)}^{R(b-x)}\frac{\sin(w)}{w}dw
$$
If $x < a < b$ or if $a < b < x$, then the above clearly tends to $0$ as $R\rightarrow\infty$ because the upper and lower limits both tend to $\infty$ or both tend to $-\infty$. If $a < x < b$, then the above tends to the improper integral
$$
   \frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(w)}{w}dw = 1.
$$
(You can look up this improper integral in any number of sources.)

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Do you have any ideas how to show $(*)(*)$?

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS : That's the standard Fourier inversion integral, and you're applying it to a function that is piecewise smooth. So the inversion integral converges to the original function, except at the points of discontinuity of $\chi_{[a,b]}$ where it converges to the mean of the left- and right-hand limits (i.e., 1/2 in this case.)

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS : Are you wanting another proof of the Fourier inversion formula in this case?

Comment: If it's possible you could show $(*)(*)$ in any way you like it'd be highly appreciated (:

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS : Do you know the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma that $\lim_{s\rightarrow\pm\infty} \int_a^b e^{isx}f(x)dx =0$ for any integrable $f$?

Comment: Nope, how can it be used? I can try to understand from a solution if possible.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts seems like a good answer , can you maybe finish it? I'm sure that if you will add few more lines it will be worth it..

Comment: @user2323232 : There are a variety of ways to show the desired equality (\*)(\*) holds, but I chose the most elementary I could think of. It requires knowing that $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin(u)}{u}du=\frac{\pi}{2}$. This integral can be found many sources.

Comment: @user2323232 I forgot to tell you that I added what you wanted to finish up.

Comment: Would love if you could take a look; https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3233541/show-that-int-infty-inftyfx-overline-gxdx-frac12-pi-int?noredirect=1#comment6658864_3233541

Answer (score 4):

In the notation set above, it is easy to show that, since the rectangular pulses never overlap due to the ordering prescribed:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{a_j b_j}(x)f_{a_k b_k}(x)dx=(b_j-a_j)\delta_{jk}$$

and the basis of functions chosen is orthogonal. Now, we substitute in the above integral the inverse Fourier transform expression and we swap the order of integration as follows:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{a_j b_j}(x)f_{a_k b_k}(x)dx=\int \frac{d\mu d{\mu'}}{(2\pi)^2}\hat{f}_{a_j b_j}(\mu)\hat{f}_{a_k b_k}(\mu')\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{i(\mu+\mu')}dx=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}d\mu\hat{f}_{a_j b_j}(\mu)\hat{f}^*_{a_k b_k}(\mu)$$

where we have used $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{i\mu x}dx=2\pi\delta(\mu)$ and also the fact that $f_{a_jb_j}(x)$ is real, which implies that $\hat{f}_{a_jb_j}(-\mu)=\hat{f}^*_{a_jb_j}(\mu)$. Now it should be easy to prove Parseval's theorem since:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|\hat{f}(\mu)|^2d\mu=\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^{n}c_jc^*_k\int d\mu \hat{f}_{a_j b_j}(\mu)\hat{f}^*_{a_k b_k}(\mu)=2\pi\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^{n}c_jc^*_k\int dx f_{a_j b_j}(x)f_{a_k b_k}(x)\\=2\pi\int dx (\sum_{j=1}^n c_j f_{a_j b_j}(x))(\sum_{j=1}^n c_j f_{a_j b_j}(x))^*=2\pi \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx|f(x)|^2$$

and the proposition is proven.(Note that exchanging summation and integration is justified since the summation is finite)

Relation (2) does not need to be proven by explicit calculation to prove (*), due to the nice properties of the Fourier transform. However, if one wants to go the long way, it is not hard to prove by algebraic manipulations on equation (1) that:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} d\mu \frac{1-\cos\mu t}{\mu^2}e^{-i\mu x}=\pi (|t|-|x|)\mathbb{1}_{|t|\geq|x|}$$

and then one can explicitly evaluate the integral 
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}d\mu \hat{f}_{a_jb_j}(\mu) \hat{f}^*_{a_kb_k}(\mu)=\\2\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{i\mu \Delta_{jk}/2}}{\mu^2}(\cos(\frac{\mu\Delta_{jk}}{2})-\cos(\frac{\mu S_{jk}}{2}))=\\\pi(|S_{jk}|-|\Delta_{jk}|)\mathbf{1}_{|S_{jk}|-|\Delta_{jk}|\geq 0}=2\pi(b_j-a_j)\delta_{jk}$$

where$$S_{jk}=a_j+a_k-b_j-b_k~~~,~~~ \Delta_{jk}=b_j+a_j-b_k-a_k$$

and the Kronecker delta arises after some mildly tedious case work from the ordering of the partition of the interval $[a,b]$.

Comment: what do you mean when writing $f^*_{a_kb_k}$ what is this $*$ at the functions?

Comment: Notation for complex conjugate

Comment: Hey Dino, very appreciated! will review this in depth soon. Could you take a look at similar question I got stuck with https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3233541/show-that-int-infty-inftyfx-overline-gxdx-frac12-pi-int/3233653?noredirect=1#comment6653632_3233653

Answer (score 2):

See the short nice proof in the lecture notes of Piotr Hajlasz at

http://www.pitt.edu/~hajlasz/Notatki/Harmonic%20Analysis2.pdf

Theorem 2.31