# Show that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\overline {g(x)}dx = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \hat{f}(\mu)\overline{\hat{g}(\mu)}d\mu.$

Tags: linear-algebra, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

**Given:** Show that if f(x) is defined as:

The Fourier transform $\hat(\mu)$ of a function $f(x)$ specified on $\mathbb R$ is often defined by the formula:

$$\hat{f}(\mu) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{i\mu x}f(x)dx \quad for \;\mu \in \mathbb C$$

Also, $g(x)$ is just another function of the same form as $f(x)$. Then:

**Question:**
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\overline {g(x)}dx = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \hat{f}(\mu)\overline{\hat{g}(\mu)}d\mu.$$

**Intuition:**
I'm trying to use the inner product space $\sum_{k=1}^4i^k\langle f+i^kg, f+i^kg\rangle = 4\langle f,g\rangle$ to solve this.

More precisely, use this Lemma:
[image]

(fixed intuition)

Comment: Do you really mean to have your integrals as

$$\int_{\infty}^\infty \cdots$$

instead of 

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \cdots$$

(i.e. shouldn't you have $-\infty$ as the lower bound?)

Comment: $f\mapsto \hat f$ is an isometry so the result follows from the polarization identity

Comment: @EeveeTrainer Fixed that. Thanks :)

Comment: Does the bar over $g$ mean complex conjugate?

Comment: @bob.sacamento yes sir. (:

Comment: It is difficult to answer your question because it is not clear what your knowledge about the Fourier transform is. I dislike citing myself, but [what I said regarding your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3230604/show-that-int-infty-inftyfx2dx-frac12-pi-int-infty-in?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment6653613_3230604) is still true: this is nothing but Plancherel's theorem in disguise. This question implies the previous one by taking $f=g$, and the previous one implies the current one by [polarization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_of_an_algebraic_form#Examples).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the polarization identity. It's use is to reconstruct the inner product from knowledge of the norm. Presumably you are trying to go from
$$
            \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|\hat{f}|^2ds = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|f|^2dx
$$
to
$$
     \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\hat{f}\overline{\hat{g}}ds = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f\overline{g}dx
$$
That's  straightforward application of the polarization identity because
$$
           f\,\overline{g}=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=0}^{3}i^n|f+i^ng|^2 \\
        \hat{f}\overline{\hat{g}}=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=0}^{3}i^n|\hat{f}+i^n\hat{g}|^2
$$
and
$$
         \int|\hat{f}+i^n\hat{g}|^2ds=\int|\widehat{f+i^n g}|^2ds=\int|f+i^ng|^2dx
$$

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: why does the last row is true?

Comment: @user2323232 : Plancherel gives $\|\widehat{f+i^ng}\|^2=\|f+i^ng\|^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Substitute your expression for $\hat{f}$ into the RHS integral.  Now substitute the similar expression for $\bar{\hat{g}}$ as well, and remember that this is the complex conjugate.  For clarity, make the integration variable on $g$ equal to, for example $x^\prime$.  Now, you will have two exponential factors that can be combined into $e^{i\mu(x-x^\prime)}$.  Pull that factor out into the integral over $\mu$.  Do you know what

$\displaystyle
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}d\mu e^{iu(x-x^\prime)} $

gives?

Comment: I'm not quite sure, would love to know what the integral equals to. (very appreciate your help)

Comment: It's a very commonly used result.  You should really learn it if you are going to be using Fourier transforms.  Take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#History , especially the last integral in the section.

Comment: @bob.sacamento this way does work , but if you want to solve it without a delta function what way can you take?

Comment: @user2323232   Dont' know.  This is the way I've always seen it done.  WOuld be happy to learn more.

Comment: Look at the second answer :)

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS  Interesting.  I wasn't aware of that.  Thanks.